# Locking Optimistic in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locking, optimistic-locking

I try to read and practice like [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and execute example below

```
p1 = Person.find(1)
p2 = Person.find(1)

p1.first_name = "Michael"
p1.save

p2.first_name = "should fail"
p2.save # Raises an ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

I do it on `rails console`, but I don't see any `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` I see it still work and `p2.save` done successfully. Anyone can tell my why?

Answer (score 1):

In order for optimistic locking to be used by Ruby On Rails, you need to add a `lock_version` column (of type integer) to your database table first.

On each update, Rails increments this version by one. On save, it only performs the update if the current value in the database is the same as the one which was initially read.

With your example, the `p1.save` would increase the column value by one in the database. The `p2` object however has still stored the previous lower value. When attempting to save the `p2` object, Rails will detect that the `lock_version` was updated and raises an `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`.